# angular filter on click by 'last week' data

Tags: angularjs, filter

Hi I am new in angular and making my first module. This article is very helpfull. I want to filter my data by lastweek records. I have already found days by current date and given date in mysql query, On button click I am just setting value like DisTopic=1 and this works fine.

May you please tell me how can I apply filter for a range like `day>=1 && day<=7`

I am using below:-

```
filter:{'topic': DisTopic,'attachment':attch, 'days':day}
```

Please help me.

Comment: The comparison you are asking for would require a custom filter

Comment: Hi charlietfl and Himanshu, Thanks for your reply. May you please provide me a link for this or any code example. Many Thanks

Comment: google for `angular custom filter`. Will find tutorials, angular docs, examples etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1: with [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) module

As stated by other users, you could indeed do that with a custom filter. However, if you find yourself writing a lot of custom filters, I'll advise you have a look at [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) module. With this module you can do what you need with the `pick` filter :

```
<div ng-repeat="task in tasks | pick: 'days >= 1 && days <= 7'">{{task.name}}</div>
```

See **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvpfj8qb/1/)**

---

#### Solution 2: Custom filter with parameters

Template:

```
<div ng-repeat="task in tasks | dayFilter: 1 : 7">{{task.name}}</div>
```

Javascript:

```
app.filter('dayFilter', function() {
    return function(input, startDay, endDay) {
        var filterFunction = function (item) {
            return item.days >= startDay && item.days <= endDay;
        };
        return input.filter(filterFunction);
    };
});
```

See **[updated demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvpfj8qb/2/)**

Comment: Michael P. Bazos, Many thanks for your reply. But I have less number of filters so I do not want to use this module.

Comment: I want to use something like this in controller    else if (event.target.id === 'lastweek')
            {
                $scope.lastweek = function (item) {
                    if (item.days >= 1 && item.days <= 7)
                    {
                        return true
                    }

                };
            }

Comment: Filter:- filter:{topic: DisTopic,attachment:attch, days:day} | filter:lastweek

Comment: Here you are using filter module, I do not want to use this

Comment: I'm not using angular-filter module in the second solution.

Comment: I remove filter js from fiddle and this is still working fine but not working for me

Comment: Can you update the fiddle so as to reproduce the problem with relevant code from your app?

Comment: I am calling filter on click of a button like:- $filter('dayFilter');

Comment: This is not falling inside:-return function (input) {}

Comment: Then you need to filter the model on click: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvpfj8qb/4/)

Comment: yes, I also tried something like this:-  $scope.dayFilter = function (item) {
                    //console.log(item)
                    return item.days >= 1 && item.days <= 7;
                };

Comment: Hi Michael, I have tried your modified fiddle jsfiddle.net/vvpfj8qb/4 and this is working fine. But I am facing new problem now. As you know I am working many filters here. After applying, this refines data and filles in the scope but other filter also works on new scope data which is wrong. I need to clear this filter after clicking on other filter

Comment: This is a different problem, please mark this question as solved as this is the case. You could open a new one, but the solution should be obvious to you. Store the unfiltered array of elements, other filters should work on the unfiltered array ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvpfj8qb/5/)).

Comment: As we are overwriting  $scope.nodes = $scope.nodes.filter(filterLastWeek); Then how can we store this to original on other filters

Answer (score 0):

Custom filter example, you can modify as per your need.

Controller

```
    $scope.search = function (item) {
        if ($scope.searchUser == null || $scope.searchUser.trim() == "")
            return true;
        if (item.FirstName.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchUser.toLowerCase()) != -1 || item.LastName.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchUser.toLowerCase()) != -1 || item.Role.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchUser.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
```

and than call it in your view

```
 | filter:search
```

So, depending on your requirement, you can pass as many parameters and modify method in controller.

Comment: I will try this now, Thanks

Comment: You need to write custom filter inside your controller and than use in your ng-repeat as i stated above. Let me know if you need more help on it.

Comment: I am using this:- node in nodes| filter:{topic: DisTopic,attachment:attch, days:day} | filter:lastweek and  else if (event.target.id === 'lastweek')
            {
                $scope.lastweek = function (item) {
                    if (item.days >= 1 && item.days <= 7)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                };
            } in controller, but this is not working

Comment: I want to call this on lastweek option selection

Answer (score 0):

```
//Below code solve my problem.

Date.prototype.getWeek = function () {
// Create a copy of this date object  
var target = new Date(this.valueOf());

// ISO week date weeks start on monday  
// so correct the day number  
var dayNr = (this.getDay() + 6) % 7;

// ISO 8601 states that week 1 is the week  
// with the first thursday of that year.  
// Set the target date to the thursday in the target week  
target.setDate(target.getDate() - dayNr + 3);

// Store the millisecond value of the target date  
var firstThursday = target.valueOf();

// Set the target to the first thursday of the year  
// First set the target to january first  
target.setMonth(0, 1);
// Not a thursday? Correct the date to the next thursday  
if (target.getDay() !== 4) {
    target.setMonth(0, 1 + ((4 - target.getDay()) + 7) % 7);
}

// The weeknumber is the number of weeks between the   
// first thursday of the year and the thursday in the target week  
return Math.ceil((firstThursday - target) / 604800000) - 1; // 604800000 = 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
```

};

Comment: I did not create fiddle for this. You please just copy code in your file and check.